# Cannot install 'auto-complete-auctex' in Emacs27, yasnippet not found

Tags: emacs, latex

I've tried to install 'auto-complete-auctex' package via MELPA.

I have a problem, yasnippet package is not found.

```
if: https://melpa.org/packages/yasnippet-20180526.1133.el: Not found
```

I looked at yasnippet package page on melpa.org and its version is 20180606.1722 not 20180526.1133 .

How can I do? or there are other ways to install 'auto-complete-auctex'.

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: What happens if you just install yasnippet and then reinstall auto-complete-auctex? Sounds vaguely like a bug in the latter; it should declare its dependencies. But the error message in your question is weird and probably incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like your package descriptions are out of date. Try evaluating:

```
(package-refresh-contents)
```